# Saving image from Picasso to memory

Tags: android, memory, picasso

I'm need to save the image which i'm setting to an imageview into internal memory, so that when the user is offline i can use those images directly from the memory . 
So far , i have tried using `Target` but i'm getting error while setting the bitmap to imageview.
Is there any way to do it without effecting the performance ?

```
private static Target getTarget(final String url, final ImageView thumbIV){
    Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    thumbIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + url);
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
                        ostream.flush();
                        ostream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Picasso will cache for you automatically.  You can influence size of disk/memory cache.  For example

```
    long maxHeapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();

    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
            .memoryCache(new LruCache((int)maxHeapSize/3))
            .build();
```

Comment: Of if i were to run the app in offline mode , will it fetch the right images ?